# dynamically update checkbox

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a checkbox that is remoddeled to look like a toggle switch.

When I refresh the page php gets the value from mysql and sets the box as either checked or unchecked accordingly. When I click the switch it updates the value in sql.

My issue now is I want it to dynamically update.

If I switch the switch on my ipad, I want my laptop to reflect it without having to refresh the page.

Is there some property that I can call so when I click the switch it sets the property of the switch using jquery dynamically?

Comment: you'll need to write a polling function

Comment: Websockets would be another option.

Comment: use websockets to update. you may want to check out `socket.io` or `sock.js` with `node.js`

Comment: Regarding the websockets comments, I think there is no support for IE 9 which is still quite popular.  That's something you should consider before implementing such a thing.

Comment: I am currently using a javascript timer function to update some divs and sliders every 15 secs .. could I include the checkbox within this?